# How to get size of String array

Tags: arrays, string, arduino

I create a string array in "Arduino" like this:

```
String commandList[] = {"dooropen", "doorlock"};
```

And in my code I want to know size of this array and I don't want define size of this array like bottom code:

```
#define commandListArraySize 2
```

I try to get size of this variable like this:

```
int size = sizeof(commandList);
```

But the returned `size` = `12`.

Comment: Don't spam tags. Arduino is not C and not exactly C++.

Answer (score 4):

I like template Array Size variant as it can't be used with pointer type:

```cpp
// Solution proposed by @TylerLewis:
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])

// Template based solution:
template<typename T, size_t N> size_t ArraySize(T(&)[N]){ return N; }

int test(String * ptr);

void setup() {
  String arr[] = {"A", "B", "C"};
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(ArraySize(arr));  // prints 3
  Serial.println(ARRAY_SIZE(arr)); // prints 3

  test(arr);
}

void loop() {
}

int test(String * ptr) {
  // Serial.println(ArraySize(ptr));  // compile time error
  Serial.println(ARRAY_SIZE(ptr));    // prints 0 as sizeof pointer is 2 and sizeof String is 6
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution, making it safer to use that the only style C approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for the length of string array, sizeof method returns the length of all characters in array. So let's count on that:

```
String commandList[] = {"dooropen", "doorlock"}; 
int a = 0;
int counter = 0;
while(counter < sizeof(commandList)){
  counter += sizeof(commandList[a]);
  a++;
}
int arrayLength = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are the in scope that the array was created (you aren't passing the array to a function), you can use this common macro:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])
```

and use it like so:

```
String[] myStrings{"Hello", "World", "These", "Are", "Strings"};
for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(myStrings); i++) {
    Serial.println(myStrings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String commandList[] = {"dooropen", "doorlock"}; 

int size = commandList.length;
```

Comment: would be nice, but not working. Gives compile error:

‣ request for member 'length' in 'filelist', which is of non-class type 'String [15]'